# Can't set background image to container from assets

Tags: flutter

I faced with the following problem: I want to add image for container's background. For this purpose I created a folder `images` in the root of my project. And here I added `background.png`. Also I added such lines to `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - images/
```

After I added this lines to my screen's class:

```
Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("images/backround.png")),
        )),
```

But when I run the app I get the following exception:

```
I/flutter ( 4072): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
I/flutter ( 4072): Unable to load asset: images/backround.png
```

So, I don't understand what's the problem. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you have typo , please change

```
backround.png
```

to

```
background.png
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Such a dummy mistake that I feel guilty for taking your time :)

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it help you, thanks.